# Refreshing table view upon changing selected index of tab controller

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a tab bar controller which has three tabs:

- Dashboard
- Link account
- Profile

On the link account page, there is a form which creates a database entry and navigates back to the dashboard tab upon clicking the following button:

[image]

However, the entry that's created in the database doesn't show in a table view on my dashboard because 'viewDidLoad' doesn't get called.

So, what is the best way of me refreshing this table by calling the following function upon navigating back to the dashboard?

The function that gets called in my viewDidLoad on my dashboard is called 'fetchAccounts':

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchAccounts()
}
```

And for reference, here is the link account button as an action:

```
@IBAction func linkAccount(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
        }
```

Please let me know if that isn't clear!

Answer (score 1):

It is but obvious that viewdidLoad will not fire because you are using tab bar controller and it is already loaded once,  so you can call that fetch account method in view will appear, you can manage a user default variable that will check that it is has came from link to account tab or not and then you can call fetch account  if that variable is true.

Comment: Yep you’re right - if I set my variables to be empty on viewDidDisappear then call that function on viewWillAppear it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.